# WebSocket onclose calling only once

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm editing one website's javascript and I want my script to reconnect when connection with WebSocket has been lost.

```
var reconnect = 0;
WS.onclose = function(event){
bot_debug("Connection has been lost, reconnecting...",0); WS = null;setTimeout(connect,1000);console.log("reconnecting");reconnect++;
};
```

WS is a variable for websocket. The code works only one time - when the server disconnects, script works as intended (it reconnects), but if connection has been lost one more time, this code just doesn't work at all. What could be the cause?

connect() function (it's website's function, not mine):

```
function connect() {
  if (!WS) {
    chat('italic', 'Generating authentication token...');
    $.ajax({
      url: '/scripts/getToken.php',
      success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
          if (data == 'nologin') {
            chat('italic', 'Please sign in through Steam to connect.');
          } else if (data == 'max') {
            chat('italic', 'CSGODouble servers are currently full - please try back later.');
          } else {
            chat('italic', 'Connecting to server...');
            WS = new WebSocket(HOST + '/' + data);
            WS.onopen = function () {
              chat('italic', 'Connected!');
            };
            WS.onerror = function (event) {
              chat('italic', 'Error: Connected closed.');
            };
            WS.onclose = function (event) {
              WS = null;
              chat('italic', 'Connection lost...');
            };
            WS.onmessage = onMessage;
          }
        } else {
          chat('italic', 'Error: Failed to get AT');
        }
      },
      error: function (err) {
        chat('italic', 'Error: Failed to get AT');
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Error: Existing connection found');
  }
}
```

Comment: Please recheck your condition of variable `data`. Make sure that it falls to `else` group so that ws connection can be reestablished.

Comment: But if I call the function in console like
connect();
It's working fine

Comment: After you call connect, WS becomes a new instance of WebSocket, which you didn't bind the onclose event yet.

Comment: @19greg96 thanks a lot, do you have some idea how to do that, without editing the connect(); source  code?

Comment: @NedasMikoleika It's been a long time since I've done js, but I think it goes something like: in your setTimeout don't call connect, call a function that calls connect and binds your event after that. So I guess you would have to wrap your entire code into a function and call that function every time after you call connect (in your timeout function)

Comment: @NedasMikoleika nahh sorry, that won't work as connect calls $.ajax which is async, your best option is redefining the connect function, or going dirty and setting an other timeout that waits for the ajax to complete

Comment: Yeah I thought the same, thanks for help anyway.

Comment: @NedasMikoleika however, I think it's possible to redefine the connect function by running `connect = function () {...}`

Comment: yeah fixed this issue already, I just redefined connect(); function as you said. I made it to reconnect(); and then just bind WS.onclose to reconnect();